# For an operator $\hat A$, if $\langle \hat A\rangle=0$, does this mean that $\langle \hat A\rangle\langle\hat A\rangle=0\,?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, operator-theory, expectation

Consider an arbitrary operator $\hat A$, let's suppose that $\langle \hat A\rangle=0$.

Does this mean that I conclude that $$\langle \hat A^2\rangle=0\,?$$

I used to think that the answer to this was **no**, we cannot conclude that the expectation value of the operator squared is zero just because the expectation value of the operator is zero.

However, $\hat A^2=\hat A\hat A$, now since $\langle \hat A\rangle=0$ does this mean that $$\langle \hat A\rangle\langle\hat A\rangle=0\,?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that $\langle \hat A \rangle = 0$ does *not* imply $\langle \hat A^2 \rangle = 0$ but it of course implies $\langle \hat A \rangle^2 = \langle \hat A \rangle\langle \hat A \rangle= 0.$